# SSL certificate from and online domain on a development server?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a site that is active/online, that have an SSL certificate.

Can I use the same certificate, on a development site, that **is also online**, that can be access by ip ?

On the development site I'm using Linux/NGINX.

More info:

1. The development site will not use the same hosting/technologies when will be active as the current website
2. I want other people besides the development to access the development website
3. Because the domain will remain the same, and the SSL is on the domain, I wanted to set the correct SSL on dev to prepare to replace the other website
4. The dev server is on a public VPS

---

Taking from answers, please explain: the development website must work if called by the same name that your current site is ?

I'm confuse, When I type the domain name will always trigger the active website(both are public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate is valid for a name, not for an IP address.

You can use the same certificate, as long as you can reach the other site by the same name. If this just refers to your development machine or a group of developers, you can edit the `hosts` file or have a DNS server resolve the name to the IP address of your development site. The question is whether this is worth the effort. If the number of developers is small, it is easier to tell them to just accept the certificate.

If you want other people to access the development site, such as for beta testing, just get a DNS name and a certificate for the development site. Use a Let's Encrypt certificate, it's free.

**Edit**

1. It doesn't matter for the certificate whether the development site uses the same technologies as the active website.
2. As stated, a certificate is valid for a name, not for an IP address. You need a DNS name and a certificate for the development site.
3. If "domain will remain the same" means that you have a wildcard certificate, as in `*.example.com`, then it will work for both `www.example.com` and `dev.example.com`. However, if your certificate is for `www.example.com`, then it will not work for `dev.example.com` just because part of the name is the same.
4. It doesn't matter where your dev and production server are.

Comment: I added some information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the same certificate if some conditions matches:

- the developement website must work if called by the same name that your current site is
- you need to somehow have this site name resolve to the development ip address (either by modifying a hosts file, or by using a custom DNS server)